# Replacing span element with input element

Tags: javascript

**Problem**

Once the input is entered in the `input` field, and the check button is clicked, the `input` element gets converted into a `span` element and the check icon gets converted into an edit icon.

I want that when someone clicks on the edit icon, the `span` element gets converted into the `input` element again.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

// Creating a SPAN element and appending it to div
container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".icons");
  if (tgt) {
    if (tgt.classList.contains("swapped")) return; // stop
    if (tgt.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
      tgt.classList.add("swapped");
      let texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".items");
      texts.forEach((text, i) => {
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        let val = document.createTextNode(text.value ? text.value : "");
        span.appendChild(val);
        span.classList.add("text2");
        items[i].appendChild(span);
        if (text.value) text.value = ""; // setting the input value to empty once clicked onto the check button
        text.parentNode.replaceChild(span, text);
        let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".mainicon"); // changing icon from check to edit
        if (tgt.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
          Array.from(btns).forEach((ele) => {
            ele.classList.toggle("hidden");
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<body style="background-color: #007bff">
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <h1 class="heading">Details Collector</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items">
        <label class="label" for="Name">Name :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="text" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <label class="label" for="State">State :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="text" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="items">
        <label class="label" for="Country">Country :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="text" type="text" />
      </div>


      <div class="check-icon icons mainicon">
        <i class="fa fa-check " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="edit-icon icons hidden mainicon">
        <i class="far fa-edit " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>


      <div class="plus-icon icons ">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL28n415/1/)

Comment: I think the functionality you are looking for, can be achieved by setting the `disabled` attribute on the input field. When the button is clicked, you can set all the inputs to be `disabled` and when the edit button is clicked, you can simply remove the `disabled` attribute. You can style the disabled fields differently as well. But this will not work if you want to have specifically `span` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js file.

Modify the check-icon help block a bit, add the following code in the loop of btns.

```
if (ele.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
    ele.classList.remove("swapped");
}
```

Adding this additional if block will help.

```
    if (tgt.classList.contains("edit-icon")) {

      let texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text2");
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".items");
      texts.forEach((text, i) => {
        let input = document.createElement("input");
        input.value = text.textContent;
        input.classList.add("text");
        items[i].appendChild(input);
        text.parentNode.replaceChild(input, text);

        let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".mainicon"); // changing icon from check to edit
        Array.from(btns).forEach((ele) => {
          ele.classList.toggle("hidden");
if (ele.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
            ele.classList.remove("swapped");
            }

        });

      });

    }
```

[jsFiddel link](https://jsfiddle.net/6pu18yrk/22/)

Answer (score 0):

Created a span element next to inputs, hidden by default.
Created 2 different click events for edit and check buttons.
On click one element type is made hidden and the other looses its hidden class.

Did not work on styling so you may want to do that yourself.
Also it's better to change `.span` class to something appropriate.

Khalil's suggestion about making inputs `disabled` sound good, too.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const editIcon = document.querySelector(".edit-icon");
const checkIcon = document.querySelector(".check-icon");

const inputs = [...container.querySelectorAll('.text')]
const spans = [...container.querySelectorAll('.span')]

editIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    spans.forEach((el, i) => {
    el.classList.add('hidden');
    inputs[i].classList.remove('hidden');
  })
  editIcon.classList.add('hidden');
  checkIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
})

checkIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputs.forEach((el, i) => {
    spans[i].textContent = el.value;
    el.classList.add('hidden');
    spans[i].classList.remove('hidden');
  })
  checkIcon.classList.add('hidden');
  editIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
})
```

```css
.mainContainer {
  height: 400px;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 200px auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.heading {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 230px 230px 50px 50px 50px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  width: 130px;
}

.icons {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin-left: 12px;
  color: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #007bff">
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <h1 class="heading">Details Collector</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="items">
          <label class="label" for="Name">Name :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input class="text" type="text" />
          <span class="span hidden"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
          <label class="label" for="State">State :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input class="text" type="text" />
          <span class="span hidden"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
          <label class="label" for="Country">Country :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input class="text" type="text" />
          <span class="span hidden"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="check-icon icons mainicon">
          <i class="fa fa-check " aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="edit-icon icons hidden mainicon">
          <i class="far fa-edit " aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>


        <div class="plus-icon icons ">
          <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```